# Use reactjs with wpml to show translated pages

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, wpml

I have a headless wordpress for backend and I am using reactjs for the frontend.

I use the wp rest api for fetching my posts data, but I can not connect the translated pages together. I have the wpml plugin installed with the swedish as default language, and have already created some posts to a secondary language (English).

I can see the English posts by adding ?lang=en at the end of the wp-json/wp/v2/posts.
Is there any way to bring a field in my original api call result for a single post, which will contain the id of the translated post, or the slug?

I need to create a language switcher for the frontend, so when you see a swedish post for example and click on the English version, it will make a new api call, fetching the data for the English version of the post.

Comment: Were you able to make progress?

Comment: Yes, by installing this plugin https://github.com/shawnhooper/wpml-rest-api. Then I used the results at the api call to make my custom functions work with these.